# For Azure AD, what endpoint should be called to make sure it is accessible?

Tags: azure-active-directory

I simply want to make a call to Azure AD services to make sure it is accessible, or to validate that the client ID and tenant guids are correct. I have searched various websites including Stack Overflow and can't find the endpoint to call. Thanks in advance for the help.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out it doesn't exist at this point.

[image: Chat transcript]